# timezone_menu returns PHP formatted timezone instead CodeIgniter formatting in ExpressionEngine

Tags: codeigniter, localization, timezone, expressionengine, members

After upgrading ExpressionEngine from 2.5.2 to 2.6.1, the Member module now sets the member's localization to PHP format eg. 'Australia/Sydney' in the exp_members table.  So, when my site calls EEs Localize class it returns the PHP format instead of the CI format, which is 'UP10', generating this error:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: Australia/Sydney
Filename: libraries/Localize.php
Line Number: 735
```

It seems that there is a bug in the javascript generated by the CI Date Helper function timezone_menu(), because the  tag should be generated with the latter time zone codes (i.e. Sydney).

The mod.member_settings module generates the localization form for the user using the Localize class in the edit_localization() function.

The Localize class uses the CI Date helper timezone_menu() function to generate a localization menu, but this provides the string 'Sydney/Australia' in the  tag, which means this is what is passed back to the update_localization() function in mod.member_settings.php.

See line 1593 in mod.member_settings.php:

```
$data['timezone'] = $_POST['server_timezone'];
```

Comment: This seems more like a bug report than a question.  Also, ExpressionEngine has it's [own StackExchange site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/).  Please ask there.  Just searching that site for "timezone" shows several items that may be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll try and post it over there.

Comment: OP reposted at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/12374